# Impressão via cmd

Tags: cmd

Tenho uma impressora de etiquetas da marca O´neal, essa impressora está conetada na minha rede. Eu estou acessando uma conexão remota de um servidor dentro da minha rede. Dentro do servidor eu usei o comando `net use \\NomeDoMeuPc\NomeDaImpressora` para acessar a impressora de dentro do servidor. mas quando utilizo o comando print, tenho o retorno que o arquivo foi impresso, mas ele apenas cria um novo arquivo com o nome da impressora e nesse arquivo estão os códigos que deveriam ser impressos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você já tentou mapear ela para uma porta do servidor? *(Exemplo LPT)*

1 - No painel de controle > Dispositivos e Impressoras

2 - Clica com o botão direito no dispositivo e vai em **propriedades da impressora** (não só propriedades)

3 - Vai na aba compartilhamento e marca a opção compartilhar essa impressora em rede e defina um nome no campo abaixo.

Tente rodar de novo o net use mas dessa vez com o nome que você definiu no compartilhamento

`net use lpt1 \\192.168.x.x\<Nome-do-compartilhamento>`

Comment: Já sim, tenho um retorno do erro 67 (O nome da rede não foi encontrado)

Comment: Verifica no compartilhamento da impressora
No painel de controle > Dispositivos e Impressoras, clica com o botão direito no dispositivo e vai em **propriedades da impressora** (não só propriedades) vai na aba compartilhamento e marca a opção _compartilhar essa impressora em rede_ e defina um nome no campo abaixo
Tente rodar de novo o net use mas dessa vez com o nome que você definiu no compartilhamento

Comment: Cara,a gora estou conseguindo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Consigo imprimir da minha maquina e de dentro do servidor

Comment: De nada :D 
Vou so editar a resposta la em cima para ficar mais fácil pra alguém que ver isso no futuro